# Woocommerce Количество товаров подкатегории

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть страница категории, там выводится список подкатегорий напротив каждой должно выводиться количество лежащих в них товаров.
Вставила такой код, то, что закомментировано, не работает корректно, выводит везде 0

```
function mynew_product_subcategories( $args = array() ) {
$parentid = get_queried_object_id();
$args = array(
    'parent' => $parentid
);
$terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
if ( $terms ) {   
    echo '<div class="pet-subcat"><h3>Категории товаров </h3>';
    echo '<ul class="puk">';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {              
            echo '<li >';                        
                echo '<p>';
                    echo '<a href="' .  esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '" class="' . $term->slug . '">';
                        echo $term->name;
                    echo ' </a>';
                    // $category = get_term( $parentid, 'product_cat' );
                    // echo "($category->count)";
                    
                echo '</p>';                                                        
            echo '</li>';                                                        
    }
    echo '</ul></div>';
}
```

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'mynew_product_subcategories', 50 );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вы же получаете все данные о подкатегориях, поэтому вам не нужно получать родительскую категорию в цикле. просто выведите значение **count** для текущей категории

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo '<li >';
    echo '<p>';
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '" class="' . $term->slug . '">';
    echo $term->name;
    echo ' </a>';
    echo $term->count;
    echo '</p>';
    echo '</li>';
}
```